# What would a command to remove \n's from text files unless it is followed by a syslog look like?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I have broken logs that I am trying to fix with bash before sending them somewhere else, my logs have \n place at random intervals in my logs and I want to remove them unless it is the original line break from the log, since all logs start with syslogs, (example: <192>), I am trying to remove all \n's unless the start of the following line starts with

I have made this regex "<\d+?>" which matches syslogs, so I am trying to say, remove all \n's unless you match this regex, but I have no idea how to do it in bash in a shell script

For example

```
<192> SeSystemtimePrivilege SeBackupPrivilege
SeRestorePrivilege
SeShutdownPrivilege
SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege
SeUndockPrivilege
<198> SeShutdownPrivilege SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege SeUndockPrivilege
```

I would like to **assemble** all the lines into one **exept the ones** that **start** with the syslog header **<num>**

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: You did not paste the command which would use the regex you have posted, so we can't even say whether your regex makes sense, in particular since neither bash nor sed understand `\d` as a special regex element.

Comment: @user1934428 I did not paste the command that would use this regex because I don't know what comand to use, nor do I know that regex is the solution, it was just one of my leads so that is why I talked about it, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @JamesBrown I edited the original post to include an example, I hope this helps !

Comment: Non-greedy matching is also a Perl extension which is not supported in most traditional regex tools.

Comment: Since different tools have different regular expressions, it does not make sense to start the solution with a regex without also expressing which program to use. Also, you showed an example input, but you did not show the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Awk script which adds a newline only if the next line matches.

```
awk '/^<[1-9][0-9]*>/ { if (p) printf "\n" }
  { printf "%s" $0; p=1 }
  END { if(p) printf "\n" }' file
```

Forgetting to print the last entry is a common beginner mistake; the `END` block is a slightly clumsy way to handle this, but easy enough to understand.